# Jquery slide left to right makes div jump up on slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create an effect where when a link is clicked it makes the initial div slide to left and reveal the second div sliding to the left and when a link is clicked from the second div the div slides to the right with the first div sliding right as well.

Here is my code so far

HTML

```
<div id="box1">
    <a href="#" id="click1">Click to show other div</a>
     <br>
    Ut accumsan dignissim lorem non posuere.Aliquam iaculis nibh    ultricies sem amet.Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad posuere.
</div>

<div id="box2" style="display:none">
    <a href="#" id="click2">Click to show other div</a>
     <br>
    Ut accumsan dignissim lorem non posuere.Aliquam iaculis nibh    ultricies sem amet.Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad posuere.
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#click1').click(function () {
        $('#box1').hide("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, 1000);
        $('#box2').show("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 1000);
    });
    $('#click2').click(function () {
        $('#box2').hide("slide", {
            direction: "right"
        }, 1000);
        $('#box1').show("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle Link with what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/rayshinn/abNmN/4/

The issue is that when I click the link and invoke the slide animation the second hidden div jumps into place. Is there a way I can create a smooth animation from left to right without the div poping/jumping effect?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use absolute positioning inside a relative-positioned wrapper.

[Fiddle exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/abNmN/6/) (updated)

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="slidingDiv" id="box1">...</div>
    <div class="slidingDiv" id="box2" style="display:none">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

#wrapper div {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Javascript auto-height calculation

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$('.slidingDiv').each(function() {
    if($(this).height() > maxHeight) maxHeight = $(this).height();
});
$('#wrapper').height(maxHeight);
```

Comment: great solution! however all my divs within the wrapper now seem to stacked over each other due to the #wrapper div{position:absolute} attribute. Any ideas for this fix? Thanks again.

Comment: The problem is, when you are using position:relative with absolute-positioned elements inside, the height of the wrapper is not set by the browser. You have 2 solutions to work around this issue.
The first one is to add a fixed value to the style of the wrapper. The second one is to add a little script wich auto calculate the height of the wrapper based on the size of the components inside the wrapper. I'm going to edit my post with the second solution.

Comment: Could I create just this same animation with custom js not with UI @pdegand59?